# Теряются данные в Intent при нажатии на группу уведомлений

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent

Имеется приложение на Android. Приложение принимает FCM Notification Messages из firebase:

```
{
  "notification": {
    "title": "TITLE",
    "body": "BODY"
  },
  "to": "TOKEN",
  "data": {
    "eventType": "TYPE",
    "deepLink": "URL"
  }
}
```

Приложение свёруто. Приходит уведомление. При нажатии на уведомление, приложение вызывается OnCreate() сплеш-скрина. Затем оттуда осуществляется переход на нужную активити, согласно данным в запросе к Firebase.

Если отправить несколько уведомлений, то андроид в шторке уведомлений их группирует. При нажатии на группу уведомлений андроид так же восстанавливает приложение. Но данные, по которым он должен перейти на необходимую страницу отсутствуют. То есть intent.extras == null

То есть, когда мы жмём на одно уведомление - Intent заполнен корректно, всё хорошо.
Когда жмём на группу - данные в интенте теряются.

Возможно кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным поведением? Заранее спасибо за любые ответы.